# Android adapter alternative in Java FX

Tags: java, android, javafx, combobox, observablelist

I've already seached Google but didn't find any useful information.
I am using [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) for combobox to select **name** and get it's **id**. (not position index, **id** come from databse) in Android. But I don't know how to use it in JavaFx?

I have tried JavaFx [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) in a list that came from from  the database **id** and **name**.
I add to [ObservableList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html)  and `setItems(list.getName())` to Combobox.
When Combobox selected get it's position index and use this index and get real id from list. `list.getID(index)`

Is this the best/correct way? Or is there an Android Adapter alternative for Java FX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would show items that contain both `name` and `id` in the `ComboBox` and specify how the items are converted to `String`s that are shown in the `ComboBox`.

```
ComboBox<Item> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();

comboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Item("foo", "17"), new Item("bar", "9")));
comboBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<Item>() {

    @Override
    public Item fromString(String string) {
        // converts string the item, if comboBox is editable
        return comboBox.getItems().stream().filter((item) -> Objects.equals(string, item.getName())).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(Item object) {
        // convert items to string shown in the comboBox
        return object == null ? null : object.getName();
    }
});

// Add listener that prints id of selected items to System.out         
comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Item> observable, Item oldValue, Item newValue) -> {
    System.out.println(newValue == null ? "no item selected" : "id=" + newValue.getId());
});
```

```
class Item {
    private final String name;
    private final String id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Item(String name, String id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Of course you could also use a different kind of items, if that's more convenient for you. E.g. `Integer`(= indices in list) could be used and the `StringConverter` could be used to convert the index to a name from the list (and id) or you could use the ids as items of the `ComboBox` and use a `Map` to get the strings associated with the ids in the `StringConverter`.

If you want to add more flexibility in how your items are represented visually, you could use a [cellFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#cellFactoryProperty--) instead to create custom `ListCell`s (there is an example in the javadoc linked). If you use this together with a `ComboBox` of `Integer`s `0, 1, ..., itemcount-1` you could get pretty close to a android `Adapter`. However using a `StringConverter` seems to be sufficient in this case.